# Sump pump knocking after water flow if sent out

Tags: pipe, water-pressure, sump-pump

Our sump pump knocks rapidly, loud, and for 10-15 seconds each time water is  ejected/discharged.
-water flows freely out the exit pipe
-i plan on changing the check valve today 3/23/22

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a _Question_ & Answer site. Please [edit] your statement to actually ask a question so we can answer it for you. As it stands, you've simply shared information and that doesn't work well in our format - it gives us nothing to work with.

Comment: It would be good if the question were more clear, but assuming the question is "why is my sump pump knocking for 15 seconds after successfully discharging water" .... it would help if you did a little more searching ... is the knocking coming from inside the pit?  From the pump or the check valve?  Can you post a video of the knocking?  And obviously ... is it still knocking with the new check valve?

Comment: It sounds like water hammer, if the pipe is securely anchored it may solve the problem with the knocking while all the air is purged from the lines and a constant flow is achieved.

Comment: What type of sump pump is it? If it is a pedestal one the shaft might be damaged.